# MongoLab REST API : Array Slice support

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, mlab

was wondering if there is an array slice support in MongoLab's REST API. I was trying out this:

```
https://api.mongolab.com/api/1/databases/<my-db>/collections/<my-coll>?apiKey=<my-api-key>&q={_id:1234},{arrayName:{$slice:2}}
```

My schema is in the following format

```
{
    "_id": "1234",
    "arrayName": [
        {   "f_id": "661963387",
            "f_name": "Test",
        },
        {   "f_id": "661963387",
            "f_name": "Test",
        },
        {   "f_id": "661963387",
            "f_name": "Test",
        }
    ]
}
```

The query works on the terminal. Is there a way I can get it working using the REST API ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should work if you put it in the fields parameter "f".

q={'_id':1234}&f={'arrayName':{'$slice':2}}

-will